# What is wrong with paths in loader.setLocation in FXMLLoader?

Tags: java, javafx, reflection, path, fxmlloader

I am learning JavaFX with [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/)

My Code:

```
package ch.makery.address;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initRootLayout();

        showPersonOverview();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayoutInner.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("PersonOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to load fxml according to author:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayoutInner.fxml"));
rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

I get such exception:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at ch.makery.address.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:35)
    at ch.makery.address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application ch.makery.address.MainApp

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My project layout:

[image]

When I move RootLayout.fxml and PersonOverview.fxml to the same folder where MainApp.java exists everything is ok:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

I tried to write path different ways but nothing.
So, can anyone help me understand how to handle with paths and loader?

Comment: Well, in your code you refer to the package `view`, but in your project layout, you have a package called `veiw`.

Comment: OMG! Two days! Thank you James_D! I have new exception now, but this is another story)))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the `directory`.

**My code works when I change these:**

```
"view/RootLayoutInner.fxml" -> "/view/RootLayoutInner.fxml"
"PersonOverview.fxml" -> "/PersonOverview.fxml"
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: always good to try helping :) Just: in the case of the OP the problem was a typo as pointed out (and accepted, kind-of) in a comment. On the other hand: with a general project layout as shown by the OP, your suggestion wouldn't work because a slash at the start of a lookup path indicates that it is _absolute_ that is would need the full package name something like "/ch/makery/address/veiw/RootLayoutInner.fxml" (replicating the typo here in the subpackage)

Answer (score 0):

You did call the folder veiw not view.